# Trying to get property 'usergroup' of non-object in laravel7

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

i am getting error when i want fetch data from users table . I want to redirect on different url as per usergroup (Admin and user).

I was trying to condition in middleware but getting error "Trying to get property 'usergroup' of non-object"

Below is code:

```
         <?php

                namespace App\Http\Middleware;
                use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
                use Closure;
                use App\User;

                class AdminAuth
                {
                      /**
                       * Handle an incoming request.
                       *
                       * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
                       * @param  \Closure  $next
                       * @return mixed
                       */
                   public function handle($request, Closure $next)
                   {
                       if (!Auth::check() && auth()->user()->usergroup == 1) 
                       {
                           return redirect('admin/login');
                       }
                    elseif(!Auth::check() && auth()->user()->usergroup == 2) 
                    {
                         return redirect('user/login');
                     }
                     return $next($request);
            }
          }
```

Comment: First try to debuging, what do you get if  you ```dd(auth()->user())``` inside if statement ?

Comment: @EncangCutbray in dd(auth()->user() ) give NULL value? I am confused why this happened?

Comment: That it's, user not authenticated, so, you can't access usergroup property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conditions are not correct. You should be checking `Auth::check()` not negating it with `!`. Since there is no authenticated user `! Auth::check()` is returning `true` which is causing the statement on the other side of the `&&`, AND, to be evaluated. Which causes the error since there is no authenticated user.

Adjust your conditions to short circuit correctly:

```
if (Auth::check() && auth()->user()->usergroup == 1) {
    ...
elseif (Auth::check() && auth()->user()->usergroup == 2) {
    ...
}
```

This way if `Auth::check()` returns a `false` equivalent value it will not try to evaluate the statement `auth()->user()...`.